# HTML Footer changes position on window resize

Tags: html, resize, window, footer

I have a simple `html` page. Header, Contents and Footer. The problem is when I resize the window. A space which height is equivalent with how high I resize the window. This happens because I have a min-height set to the Contents `div`. How can I make the Footer remain on bottom after I resize the window? :( Please help

Here is my code: http://snipt.org/uHlm1

Here is the webpage: http://www.4shared.com/rar/gzs1zQHw/Website01.html

Comment: If it is a simple as you say it is, please code it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar

Answer (score 0):

Give the body an absolute position. Then either put the footer directly in the body instead of the dialog-box, or give the dialog-box an absolute position too.